# Crossfilter: filtering by X and Y for scatter plot

Tags: crossfilter

Assuming I have an array of objects like that:

```
[{xVal: 9.7, yVal: 100},
{xVal: 12.3, yVal: 40},
{xVal: 12.4, yVal: 60}, ...]
```

I would like to filter it and reduce its size significantly to use in a scatter plot. I have been trying out some things but was left a bit confused about correct practices but also the API documentation at some point. From what I understand, filters stack, so I tried this:

```
let xDim: Dimension<ITest, number> = cf.dimension((d: ITest) => d.xVal)
let yDim: Dimension<ITest, number> = cf.dimension((d: ITest) => d.yVal)
yDim.filterRange([40, 80])
let xDimGrouped: any = xDim.group((d: number) => Math.round(d))
```

My intention is to eventually group based on x and y while also being able to filter it. In the code above, the filter is ignored as soon as it is being grouped (`xDim.top(3)` would return a filtered array though).

To group by two values I have tried this:

```
let combDim: Dimension<ITest, string> = cf.dimension((d: ITest) => Math.round(d.xVal)+':'+d.yVal)
let yDim: Dimension<ITest, number> = cf.dimension((d: ITest) => d.yVal)
```

This works but would require to split all keys in the end to retrieve x and y for the plot. Unless I am missing something. But here the same problem also occurs. Filtering `yDim` would affect `combDim.top(3)` but not the group.

The [API documentation](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group) says that 
*"a grouping intersects the crossfilter's current filters, except for the associated dimension's filter. Thus, group methods consider only records that satisfy every filter except this dimension's filter. So, if the crossfilter of payments is filtered by type and total, then group by total only observes the filter by type."*

Doesn't that mean that a filter on `yDim` should affect the `grouping` of `combDim`?

**Edit:**

I have created an example of what I meant: https://jsfiddle.net/e98not64/2/

It turns out that `all()` always returns all members of the group, but updates the `value` property according to its occurrences with filters applied. I didn't notice this before and thought it is ignoring the filters because I checked for the size of the groups and the array returned :x I could just check if the value is `> 0` and split the `key` value to get `x` and `y`. Would that be the right approach/a good way to do it?

Comment: Looks to me like it should work. You aren’t showing us your output of the group or what you would expect. Please add that as well as the full code you use to get to that point. Even better would be an interactive example, but a full explanation of what you’ve done, what happened, and how that is different from what you expect is really the minimum we would need to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought I had done most of that already but it at least wasn't very clear then. I have added a jsfiddle example and tried to elaborate on my problem/confusion before.

Comment: Cool, thanks. And yes, the approach you have outlined is a good one!

Comment: I guess you answered my question by making me write a proper example then :D
It seemed a bit.. "hacky" but if that is a valid approach, then I think I can start addding filters everywhere. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, that’s how Crossfilter groups work. Just the value changes. Once a group exists, it generally sticks around. The reason is that a counting group is just a special case of a more general purpose group where you can do any kind of calculation you want. So the library wouldn’t want to assume that the value 0 is special in any way.

Comment: Your quote from the documentation illustrates why you probably want to use the composite key rather than two dimensions. Typically when you brush on a chart, you don't want to affect that chart, only the other ones. So you need to have only one crossfilter dimension per chart or it would get confusing. And [yes, this is the recommended way](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/pull/48#issuecomment-22795301).